# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

One input example of my CNN consists of 8 x 900 arrays, like this:

```
[
[1.25 0.2 ... .90] #size = 900
   ...             # x 8
[1.25 0.2 ... .98] 
]
```

And I want to:

1. apply a **BatchNormalizer**
2. apply a **Conv layer** with **10 filters** and a **conv window of 2 x 10**

Here is my code so far:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(8,900))
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(inputs)
Conv2D = layers.Conv2D(10, (2, 10), activation='relu', input_shape=(8, 900))(x)
```

But I already get an error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: :
> expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 8, 900]

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your image grayscale or RGB?

Comment: It's not exactly an image, each input consists of 8 EEG signals (with 900 datapoints for each of them).

Comment: Then if I am not wrong you can use 1D convolution. 2D Conv is for images and expects a depth in input shape.

Comment: @Frightera The conv layer scan the EEG 2 by 2 and over 10 datapoints, so for me it more looks like 2D